# Deleting certain files in multiple folders in one directory in Linux

Tags: bash, find, rm

I have about 30+ folders I want to delete only certain file types inside.

I can do this by using:

```
Find Dir1, Dir2, Dir3 (Etc.) -name "*.filetype" -Delete
```

However, this would be very long to type/copy. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Give what you have given us, `find Dir? -name "*.filetype" -delete` would work. Remember that with `Dir?` or any other glob, the shell will expand it. So it could be `Dir*`

Comment: I should have said Folder1 instead of Dir. This would work but I would have to type out the 30 folder names. I was wondering if there is a way I could select the folders like ``` Find folder 1 - Folder 45 -name "*.filetype" -delete`` ```

Comment: Do you still have folders to exclude (such as `Folder 46`)? It would be helpful if you can provide the example of folder names you have and you want to select out of them?

Comment: I have folders up to 200. I only want to select folders 1 -30 and delete certain file types from within those selected folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
find Folder[1-30] -type f -name "*.filetype" -delete
```

- [1-30] will be expanded to 1 to 30, incrementing by one.